# Switching article states using state pattern

Tags: design-patterns, angular-2+, state, rxjs

The `Article` model supports a bunch of transitions. Only two are shown below: `star()`/`unstar()`.

Is this a valid implementation of the state pattern?

```
interface ArticleState {
  star(): ArticleState;
  unstar(): ArticleState;
  // other transitions ...
}

export class InitialArticleState implements ArticleState {
  star   = () => new StarredArticleState();
  unstar = () => this;
  // other transitions ...
}

export class StarredArticleState implements ArticleState {
  star   = () => this;
  unstar = () => new InitialArticleState();
  // other transitions ...
}

export class Article {  
  state: ArticleState = new InitialArticleState();  
  star() { this.state = this.state.star(); }
  unstar() { this.state = this.state.unstar(); }
}
```

The `Article` state operations are wrapped by the service which updates the feed:

```
@Injectable()
export class ArticlesFeedService {

  private feed$: Subject<Article[]> = new BehaviorSubject<Article[]>([]);
  private store: Article[] = [];

  private publishChanges() {
    this.feed$.next(this.store);
  }

  starArticle(article: Article): void {
    article.star();
    // update the store then publish changes...
  }
}
```

There's a component subscribed to get **starred** articles:

```
getStarredArticles(): Observable<Article[]> {
  return this.getArticles().pipe(
    map((articles: Article[]) => 
      articles.filter((article: Article) => 
        article.state instanceof StarredArticleState
      )
    )
  );
}
```

My motivation behind using the state pattern is that it helps reduce branching (decision making) in the feed service methods (e.g. **starred** article can't be **blacklisted**, only **unstarred** / **initial**).

1. Is it okay to use state as public property of the `Article`? I thought about marking the article's state property as private and introducing a readonly string tag to each state (to `ArticleState` interface), so I could subscribe/filter using the tag. But it's a string and I'm tottally not sure if it's better.
2. How can I improve the design?
3. Are there any TypeScript features that could be used instead?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I [changed the title](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/243670/revisions) so that it describes what the code does per [site goals](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask): "_State what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about it._". Feel free to [edit] and give it a different title if there is something more appropriate.

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ thanks! Well, I tried to be more descriptive, updated the title.